# Input range move only by one step

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use input range moving one by one. For exemple here is my slider :

```
<input id="replay-input" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0">
```

Really basic. But the problem is that you can freely move from 5 to 89 by one click. What I would like to achieve is to increment or decrements only by one so my value will look like this is if I move the cursor :

0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4

Then if I go back :

4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0

With big `max` like 5000 we have missing steps because there is too many values on a small area :

4800 -> 4799 -> 4790 -> 4785

Is there a way to avoid this ? One idea may be to use JS and store value and only allow change of one but maybe there is something more simple in HTML ?

https://jsfiddle.net/vcoyxg4v/5/

Thanks !

Comment: Just a suggestion, with big values like that try adding arrow buttons (left - right), or a textbox where the user can input the value without using the slide. Hope it helps you.

Comment: This totally depends on how your browser interprets a range input. If you want to have a reproducable behaviour, you should probably build your own control.

Comment: Otherwise, an input with type `number` might work out.

Comment: The problem is that I really want to keep a slider range like this since I want to create a playback system. It has to be smooth. You need to visualize it like a timeline (here is an example but mine will be with the track : http://leafletplayback.theoutpost.io/examples/example_2.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would not suggest limiting the default functionality of the slider control, as people expect it to work in a certain way: think also of dragging the slider, using the arrow/page/home/end keys when the control has focus, ...

But for the sake of the exercise, here is code that will make the slider value only increase/decrease with 1. So if you drag, the value will slowly catch up with the mouse position. This solution uses a data property to keep track of the previous value:

```js
$('#replay-input').data({
    was: $('#replay-input').val()
}).on('input', function () {
    var data = $(this).data();
    $(this).data({
        was: this.value = +data.was + (this.value > data.was || -1)
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="replay-input" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0">
```

#### Using animation

As an extension to this idea, you could use the `animate` method to take care of the progression towards the target value:

```js
$('#replay-input').data({
    current: $('#replay-input').val()
}).on('input', function () {
    var data = $(this).data(),
        value = this.value;
    $(this).data(data = {
        current: this.value = +data.current, // restore previous value
    }).stop().animate({ value }, { // ... and animate towards the target
        duration: 500, // Experiment with other durations...
        easing: 'swing', // Experiment with other easing values...
        step: function(val) {
            $(this).data({current: this.value}) // accept change
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="replay-input" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0">
```

As indicated in the comments, you can experiment a bit with the animation options `duration` and `ease` to tailor it to your needs.

There is a slight visual glitch just after a click because the slider also receives an `input` event on `mouseup`.

Comment: Thanks ! This is a great way to achieve this but it looks pretty weird to use since there is a lot of delay between the cursor and slider. Maybe I need to think about my problem in another way.

Comment: I added an alternative to my answer which uses animation. Maybe you can tailor that to your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will look into this direction to give it a try !